# TypeError: 'Int64Index' object is not callable

Tags: python, pandas, list, indexing

Why am I getting this error?

```
ticker = 'NFLX'
price = get_data(ticker, start_date='2020-01-01', end_date=None, index_as_date=bool, interval ='1d')
price.to_csv(r'D:\Python Stuff\pythonProject\NFLX.csv')
df = pd.read_csv('NFLX.csv')
price_list = df['adjclose']
change = price_list.diff(1)


def RSI():
    change.dropna(inplace=True)
    positive = change.copy()
    negative = change.copy()
    positive[positive < 0] = 0
    negative[negative > 0] = 0

    RSI_days = 5

    average_gain = positive.rolling(window=RSI_days).mean()
    average_loss = abs(negative.rolling(window=RSI_days).mean())
    relative_strength = average_gain/average_loss
    rsi = 100.0-(100.0/(1.0+relative_strength))
    return rsi

relative_strength_index = RSI()

print(relative_strength_index[-6:])

lowest_rsi = min(relative_strength_index[-6:])
print(lowest_rsi)

index_number = relative_strength_index[-6:].index(lowest_rsi)
print('index of lowest rsi = ' + index_number)
```

When I run the code, my error is "TypeError: 'Int64Index' object is not callable". How can I improve this code to resolve this error?

Comment: please point out which line exactly results in raising the exception

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace the parenthesis in `index(lowest_rsi)` by brackets

```
index_number = relative_strength_index[-6:].index[lowest_rsi.astype(int)]
print('index of lowest rsi = ' + index_number)
```

Edit: Your code should probably look something like this:

```
relative_strength_index = RSI()

print(relative_strength_index[-6:])

index_number = relative_strength_index[-6:].idxmin()
print('index of lowest rsi =', index_number)
```

Comment: this is what i got: IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices

Comment: That's because `lowest_rsi` should be an integer if you want to use it as an index. Try with `lowest_rsi.astype(int)`. I've edited my answer accordingly

Comment: Now it says: AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'astype'

Comment: Have you changed something else in your code other that what you are showing here? Like using `int(lowest_rsi)` before that line?

Comment: I did not do that

Comment: I dont know if what you are trying to accomplish can be done with the code you are showing, perhaps you should be looking to use the `argmin` function to obtain the index of the lowest value in `relative_strength_index` (an integer) instead of `min`, which returns the lowest value (a float).

Comment: that's exactly what i was trying to do. Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 2):

`relative_strength_index` is not a list but is of type pandas.Series.
Therefore, index is a property and not a method like with list, which is where your original error came from and you cannot call that property.

You should instead cast `relative_strength_index` to a list and the you can proceed to call the index method as shown below.

Also, you should cast `index_number` to a string before concatenating it.

```py
index_number = list(relative_strength_index[ -6: ]).index(lowest_rsi)
print('index of lowest rsi = ' + str(index_number))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to convert your numeric data to 32 format and object to category. In my case it helped to avoid error during xgb.DMatrix transformation.

```
for col in df.select_dtypes('int').columns:
    df[col] = df[col].astype('int32')

for col in df.select_dtypes('float'):
    df[col] = df[col].astype('float32')
    
for col in df.select_dtypes('object'):
    df[col] = df[col].astype('category')
```