# Convert string labels into integer numbers

Tags: python

I have a dataset in a dataframe form which the first column is a text and the second one it's an author. Authors are the labels for a classification task. I want to convert this column into numbers.

I tried to use the following code from [How to convert string labels to numeric values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44496057/how-to-convert-string-labels-to-numeric-values)

```
train['author'].apply(train['author'].index)
```

but it's not working. The output is

```
Int64Index object is not callable
```

Could you please help me?

Comment: Can you add a sample of `train`?

Comment: Are you saying you want to assign an integer to each unique author name?

Comment: Maybe this well help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65655266/typeerror-int64index-object-is-not-callable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC, you're trying to create numerical categories for each author. If so, try:

```
train["codes"] = train["author"].astype("category").cat.codes
```

If you then want to apply the same codes to other datasets, you could do:

```
mapper = train.set_index('author')["codes"].to_dict()
validation["codes"] = validation["author"].map(mapper)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, if I want to covert the validation set with the same encoding how can I do it? Thank you so much for your help!!!!

Comment: I was thinking that I cound create an encoding by using df["author"].astype("category").cat.codes, where df['authors'] contains all the labels and then convert the training, validation and testing sets with the same encoding

Comment: @JohnAngelopoulos - See the edit. Is that what you need?

Comment: yeah, thanks a lot. You could also replace the names by intengers without creating a new column, by just doing validation['authors'] = validation["author"].map(mapper). I think there isn't any problem if you do that. Right?

Comment: Yes but in case you don't want to overwrite your underlying data, it's better to create a new column (even to check if everything maps correctly etc.)

Answer (score 0):

```
train['author'].apply(train['author'].tolist().index)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. One more quick question, and if then I want to convert with the same encoding the validation set, I should do train['author'].apply(validation['author'].tolist().index), right?

Comment: if validation.author has all elements of train.author,

Answer (score 0):

if you want there is also the ord() built in.

```
for i in author:
  ord(i)
```

you'll have to do each individual letter.